# cannot clear textbox wtihin update panel

Tags: asp.net, textbox, updatepanel

I'm pretty new to update panels and would appreciate some help.  I have a form with a few textboxes and submit button.  Before the update panel, I would do a page validation on the button click event and if everything was okay, enter the date into a db and then clear two of the textboxes.  Then I added the update panel.  Now, the textboxes won't clear.  Everything else is working great.  Any help?

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upForm" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" 
        UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <Triggers><asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlMember"  
        EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" /></Triggers></asp:UpdatePanel>

CType(upForm.FindControl("txtAuth"), TextBox).Text = String.Empty  
txtAuth.Text = String.Empty
```

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `upForm.Update()` after setting the textbox's Text to `String.Empty`